# How can you paralellize the processing of File InputStreams in Kotlin / Arrow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, arrow-kt

I am processing large `File`s, having a list of them:

```
val originalFiles: List<File>
```

I need to read the `InputStream` of each file, process it, and write it to another processedFile. For the sake of simplicity let's assume I just read the original InputStream and write it to the destination file output stream.

I would like to process the originalFiles in parallel.

The first straigtforward way would be to use parallelStream()

```
override suspend fun processFiles(workdir: File): Either<Throwable, Unit> = either {
    
    val originalFiles = ...

    originalFiles.parallelStream().forEach {
        val destination = File("${workdir.absolutePath}/${it.name}-processed.txt")
        logger.info("Starting merge {}", destination)
        FileOutputStream(destination).use { faos ->
            IOUtils.copy(it.inputStream(), faos)
        }
        logger.info("Finished processing {}", destination)            
    }
}
```

However, given that I'm working with coroutines and Arrow, I get a compile warning `Possibly blocking call in non-blocking context could lead to thread starvation`.

- Is there a proper (non-blocking) way to work with Input/OutputStreams with coroutines/suspend functions?
- Is there a better way to paralellize the List processing with coroutines/Arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best best would be to use `parTraverse` (going to be renamed to `parMap` in 2.x.x). This function comes from Arrow Fx Coroutines, there is also `Flow#parMap` and `Flow#parMapUnordered` that you can use instead.

You also need to make sure that `FileOutputStream` is closed correctly, and in face of cancellation, and I would recommend using `Resource` for that.

The `Possibly blocking call in non-blocking context could lead to thread starvation` warning will disappear by invoking it on the correct `Dispatchers.IO`.

```kotlin
suspend fun processFiles(workdir: File): Unit {
  val originalFiles: List<File> = emptyList<File>()
  originalFiles.parTraverse(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val destination = File("${workdir.absolutePath}/${it.name}-processed.txt")
    logger.info("Starting merge {}", destination)
    FileOutputStream(destination).use { faos ->
      IOUtils.copy(it.inputStream(), faos)
    }
    logger.info("Finished processing {}", destination)
  }
}
```

So the summary the answers on your question:

> Is there a proper (non-blocking) way to work with Input/OutputStreams with coroutines/suspend functions?

Execute them using `suspend` + `Dispatchers.IO`.

> Is there a better way to paralellize the List processing with coroutines/Arrow?

Leverage `parTraverse` to parallelise the `List` transformations in Kotlin Coroutines. Optionally, `parTraverseN` if you want to also limit the amount of parallel processes.